# Java one code to stop in a loop and not stop the entire program in eclipse

Tags: java, swing

Currently in my brief time with Java I have made a clicker game and I've been trying to implement a way to add a number to an integer (or the int command) every couple of seconds. but whatever I try just stops the entire program completely such as the

```
Thread.sleep(15000);
wait(15000);
```

even if they are in a try and catch it just stops the program and not complete a loop every couple of seconds.

Comment: Your question does not appear to have anything to do with Eclipse, but rather has all to do with whatever GUI library you may be using. If this is a Swing GUI, then you're freezing the event thread by calling `Thread.sleep(...)`, and this will completely freezing the GUI. The solution would be to use a Swing Timer, but we can't tell yet till you tell us more. Most importantly, improve your question,  your tags, and show your code.

Comment: how would I know if I'm using swing?

Comment: Do you use any Swing components? JFrame, JPanel, JButton, etc...? But again, please show us pertinent code. The better the quality of the question, the better the quality of the answer. Right now you have an answer, but it's little more than a guess.

Comment: Yes I am, so how would I set up a timer?

Comment: Check out the Swing tutorial which you can find in the Swing tab's [info link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) and then look for the Swing Timer tutorial. Also you can Google `Swing Timer Tutorial` and it will be the 1st or 2nd hit. I've updated your tags, since again your question has nothing to do with Eclipse. Also improve your question as noted above.

Comment: also I tried to show my code but it said everything was not recognized as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Thread.sleep(xxx);` in the current thread, then yes, it will stop the current thread for xxx seconds. Because (most likely) `Thread.sleep` is in the same thread that is controlling the GUI, it is pausing your code from executing, freezing your application. There are two ways you can fix this:

**Create a new thread and place the timer code in there**:

SwingUtilities.invokeLater will add your Runnable to the queue of threads that AWT executes.

```
    // Because the code is in a different thread, Thread.sleep(1000) will not pause
    // the current thread and the application will continue as normal
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        int seconds = 0;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true) {

                // wait one second
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                };
                // increment seconds
                seconds++;

                System.out.println(seconds);
            }
        }

    });

    thread.start();
```

**Use an existing timer in the Java API**

Look at [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and its scheduleAtFixedRate method. [Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/java-util-concurrent-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-example/)'s an example. You could also use a swing timer as mentioned in the comment by Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

To use a Swing timer, you import javax.swing.Timer (not java.util.Timer), create a Timer object with the delay and an action listener listening for when it will fire events, and start it.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
    {
        System.out.println("Timer went off!");
    }
});

// Repeat every second
timer.start();
```

Note that this code won't execute on its own; you need to have a GUI running.

Comment: Please be sure that you show him how to do this in the context of making thread-safe Swing calls from within your background thread code, something I don't see in your answer. Since this will increase the complexity of the code quite a bit for a newbie, it is usually **much** easier to simply use a Swing Timer, since the timing portion is done in the background while all calls in the Timer's ActionListener are guaranteed to be called on the Swing event thread.

Comment: I added the code for the Swing Timer, although I thought that code for the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor would be too complicated for a beginner and unnecessary since the question is about Swing.

Comment: I'll 1+ you for the Swing Timer, but if you're going to show background thread code, then it implies that he should use this, and then you should show code within the background thread that queues a Swing call onto the Swing event thread, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable....`

Comment: Sorry, wrong change as your current code will now guarantee that the Thread.sleep will be called on the EDT. The background thread should be performed as you initially had it, inside of a `new Thread(...)`. It's just that if you want to make Swing calls from **within that thread's Runnable,** you should create a Runnable and queue it onto the Swing event thread.

Comment: Thanks M3579 This Really Helped!